# Changing the right element

Tags: jquery, html

I have this HTML code:

```
<div class="custom-input-file product-left">
    <input type="file" class="input-file" name="mediabundle_mediatype[file]" id="picture_1">
    <div class="archivo">Seleccionar ...</div>
    <img style="display:none" alt="your image" src="#" id="picPreview1">
</div>

<div class="custom-input-file product-left">
    <input type="file" class="input-file" name="mediabundle_mediatype[file]" id="picture_2">
    <div class="archivo">Seleccionar ...</div>
    <img style="display:none" alt="your image" src="#" id="picPreview2">
</div>

<div class="custom-input-file product-left">
    <input type="file" class="input-file" name="mediabundle_mediatype[file]" id="picture_3">
    <div class="archivo">Seleccionar ...</div>
    <img style="display:none" alt="your image" src="#" id="picPreview3">
</div>

<div class="custom-input-file product-left">
    <input type="file" class="input-file" name="mediabundle_mediatype[file]" id="picture_4">
    <div class="archivo">Seleccionar ...</div>
    <img style="display:none" alt="your image" src="#" id="picPreview4">
</div>

<div class="custom-input-file product-left">
    <input type="file" class="input-file" name="mediabundle_mediatype[file]" id="picture_5">
    <div class="archivo">Seleccionar ...</div>
    <img style="display:none" alt="your image" src="#" id="picPreview5">
</div>
```

And I need to run the same jQuery code for each but of course changing the ID of the elements. This is the code I made:

```
$("#picture_1, #picture_2, #picture_3, #picture_4, #picture_5").change(function() {
    readURL(this);
    $(this).parent().find(".archivo").html("Cambiar imagen");
}).css('border-width', function() {
    if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")
        return 0;
});

$(".document-file input:file").change(function() {
    $(this).parent().find(".file").html($(this).val());
}).css('border-width', function() {
    if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")
        return 0;
});
```

But don't know how to iterate trough elements and change the one I'm changing, any help?

Comment: Be aware you have multiple elements with the same ID. IDs must be unique.

Comment: @L105 I fixed as you suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace

> $("#picture_1, #picture_2, #picture_3, #picture_4, #picture_5")...

by

```
$(".input-file").change(function() {
    readURL(this);
    $(this).parent().find(".archivo").html("Cambiar imagen");
    $(this).parent().find(".file").html($(this).val());
}).css('border-width', function() {
    if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")
        return 0;
});
```

It now uses class selector (http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/).

Comment: This didn't work because it will change always the first picture and I need to change the picture on the element I was clicked

Comment: still happing the same, only the first is changed